# Binary rejected iap works on device but not in validating

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, appstore-approval

I sent a binary to review through AppStoreConnect after having tested the IAP on a real device and through TestFlight by other testers

They rejected my binary saying that "no action takes place when tapping on the IAP"

I double checked that the IAP was ready to submit and added to the build on the bottom of the form

This is the code of the button purchase :

```swift
@IBAction func showMeteoTouched(_ sender: Any) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "DroneSpot Premium", message: NSLocalizedString("UnlockMeteoAlertTitle", comment: ""), preferredStyle: .actionSheet)

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("PremiumPrice", comment: ""), style: .default, handler: { action in
            IAPHandler.shared.purchaseMyProduct(index: 0)
        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("RestoreProduct", comment: ""), style: .default, handler: { action in
            IAPHandler.shared.restorePurchase()
        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: NSLocalizedString("Cancel", comment: ""), style: .cancel, handler: nil))

        self.present(alert, animated: true)
    }
```

And my class :

```swift
class IAPHandler: NSObject {
    static let shared = IAPHandler()

    let premiumID = "dronespot.premium"

    fileprivate var productID = ""
    fileprivate var productsRequest = SKProductsRequest()
    fileprivate var iapProducts = [SKProduct]()

    var purchaseStatusBlock: ((IAPHandlerAlertType) -> Void)?

    // MARK: - MAKE PURCHASE OF A PRODUCT
    func canMakePurchases() -> Bool {  return SKPaymentQueue.canMakePayments()  }

    func purchaseMyProduct(index: Int){
        if iapProducts.count == 0 { return }

        if self.canMakePurchases() {
            let product = iapProducts[index]
            let payment = SKPayment(product: product)
            SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
            SKPaymentQueue.default().add(payment)

            print("PRODUCT TO PURCHASE: \(product.productIdentifier)")
            productID = product.productIdentifier
        } else {
            purchaseStatusBlock?(.disabled)
        }
    }

    // MARK: - RESTORE PURCHASE
    func restorePurchase(){
        SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
        SKPaymentQueue.default().restoreCompletedTransactions()
    }
```

I heard on some topics that we must wait a few hours for the in-app to be active but Apple's team reviewed my app after my TestFlight users tested it.
I will try to resubmit this evening